# CloudFront + S3 delivering previous webpage details

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

does anyone know why CloudFront delivers the previous static web page fetched from S3 bucket? I have hosted a ReactJS App on S3 and linked with CloudFront. I deleted my signup page but still on the URL [www.example.com/signup](http://www.example.com/signup) the signup webpage is still displayed without an error saying not found?

I have deleted the Signup.jsx completely from S3 bucket - No fix
I have invalidated all files in my CloudFront - No fix.
I have used different browsers, used incognito and done CTRL+F5 - No fix.

Where else could file's get cached for my website to deliver the signup page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue, it wasn't a problem with invalidations but it was because I didn't run my build configuration after each edit I did on the code. If anyone is stuck this might help.

Answer (score 0):

it's because CloudFront cache the files from origin, please invalidate/delete the files from cache and give a try.

go to the "Distribution Settings" and create "Invalidations" using regex. may this below link will help you.

i believe you are using wrong object path during invalidation,

[Invalidating files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#invalidating-objects-console)

Comment: Hi, as mentioned I have used the regex "/*" to invalidate my CloudFront cache, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: I just saw the edit for the answer, well my CloudFront is linked to bucketName. So if I was to invalidate my entire bucket (all it's files) it would simply just be "/*" to invalid all files right? Unless I missed something else. If that's the case that didn't fix it.

Comment: could you check the caching header at browser level and it's value. because CloudFront  uses these values to cache the responses from origin in edge locations

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth checking TTL for your record/ url. If you have TTL on higher side, it will take time for changes to take affect.